# TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_documents'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to  do feature extraction text with  Sklearn, however I'm getting error

> Type error:fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'raw_documents'

It seems I have to make complete some arguments with missing raw document, but i cannot find what is the caused the error, here's my code:

```
features=TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(data.status).toarray()
label=data.label
features.shape
```

When running in the Jupyter notebook console I get the following errors:

```
    TypeError   Traceback (most recent call last)\
<ipython-input-3-614f2fa78a04> in <module>()
----> 1 features=TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(data.status).toarray()
      2 label=data.label
      3 features.shape

TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_documents'
```

Answer (score 6):

In scikit-learn, everything with a `fit_transform` is an instance of some type, which is to say that you'll need to initialize that instance first, where you are calling `fit_transform` as if it were a `staticmethod`.

So, either create the instance by letting `vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()` and use `vectorizer.fit_transform(data.status)`, or just use `TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(data.status)` directly.

You can see this by having a look at [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform), noting that you seem to indeed be passing the only required argument, and recalling that instance methods in Python come with an implicit parameter, typically called `self`, so that what's happening in your code is that you're passing `data.status` as `self`, while `raw_documents` is left unset.

Comment: what should replace in raw_documents, i didnt understand your solution

Comment: @Singh: `raw_documents` ends up corresponding to `data.status`: They did `TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(data.status)` where they wanted `TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(data.status)` (note the additional parentheses).

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I'll check if this works